# Dapper QueryMultiple Read result as IDictionary

Tags: c#, dapper

I am using **Dapper** with **Oracle Managed** and trying to use `QueryMultiple` method. I have a stored procedure in an Oracle package that returns multiple recordsets. I want to reuse my code for multiple package methods and the data coming back is coming from different source tables, so columns and actual data will vary.

To handle this I have a class that uses an `IEnumerable<string>` for storing FieldNames and an `IEnumerable<object[]>` for storing the data for each row.

With just a single recordset I am able to use the `ExecuteReader` method to iterate the results and add them myself. However, I would like to use `QueryMultiple` to get everything in a single call. Right now I have two recordsets coming back but others may be added.

After a few different attempts I was able to get the following code to work. However, it seems like there should be a better way to get this. Further below is a piece of code found in another SO question that seemed to be what I wanted but I just couldn't get it to work. Does anyone have any suggestions about how I'm getting the FieldNames and Data in the code below and if there is a better way using Dapper API. Loving Dapper by the way. Thanks for any suggestions.

```cs
// class to load results into 
public class Results {
    public IEnumerable<string> FieldNames { get; set; }
    public DetailInfo Detail { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<object[]> Data { get; set; }         
}

// code to get the results from the database field names and data varies
// method is private so that external callers cannot pass any just any string as methodName
private Results GetTableResults(string methodName) {
    var queryparams = new OracleDynamicParameters();
    queryparams.Add(name: "l_detail_cursor", dbType: OracleDbType.RefCursor, direction: ParameterDirection.Output);
    queryparams.Add(name: "l_data_cursor", dbType: OracleDbType.RefCursor, direction: ParameterDirection.Output);
    // ... other parameters go here, removed for example 

    Results results = new Results(); 
    string sql = string.Format("{0}.GET_{1}_DETAILS", PackageName, methodName);  
    using (IDbConnection db = new OracleConnection(this.ConnectionString)) {
        db.Open();
        using (var multi = db.QueryMultiple(sql: sql, param: queryparams, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure)) {

            // detail in first cursor, no problems here 
            results.Detail = multi.Read<DetailInfo>().Single();

            // --------------------------------------------------
            // this is the code I'm trying to see if there is a better way to handle
            // --------------------------------------------------
            // data in second cursor 
            var data = multi.Read().Select(dictionary =>
               // cast to IDictionary 
               dictionary as IDictionary<string, object>
            );

            // pull from Keys 
            results.FieldNames = data.First().Select(d => d.Key);
            // pull from values 
            results.Data = data.Select(d => d.Values.ToArray());  
            // --------------------------------------------------
       } 
    }
    return results; 
}
```

I was attempting to try to use something like the following but only get an exception at run time about splitOn needing to be specified. I tried using something like ROWNUM to even give the recordset an "id" but that didn't seem to help.

```c#
var data = multi.Read<dynamic, dynamic, Tuple<dynamic, dynamic>>(
      (a, b) => Tuple.Create((object)a, (object)b)).ToList();
```